# batch processing - RPGLE

Tags: ibm-midrange, rpgle, rpg

I am trying to understand simple batch processing using RPGLE and PRTF members below is the code for both but the results look like this (The columns print instead of the data) What am I doing wrong:
[image]

**KDCSTPGM.RPGLE**   this is the rpgle member with logic

```
Dcl-f Customers Disk KEYED Usage(*Input);
Dcl-f Custlist Printer Usage(*Output) Oflind(Endofpage);


//Standalone variable declarations
Dcl-s Endofpage Ind Inz(*on);
dcl-s count packed(2:0);


// Main Procedure
Read Customers;

  
Dow Not %eof(Customers);
  If Endofpage;
    write Header;
    Endofpage = *off;
  Endif;

  count += 1;
  write Detail;
  Read Customers;

Enddo;

If Endofpage;
    write Header;
Endif;

write total;    

*inlr = *On;
Return;
```

**CUSTLIST.PRTF**   This is the printer file

```
A          R HEADER
 A                                  2 55'Customer List'
 A                                  2 97DATE
 A                                  2117PAGNBR
 A                                  3  3'Customer:'
 A          R DETAIL                    SPACEB(1)
 A                                     3'Customer Number'
 A                                      SPACEB(3)
 A                                    25'Last Name '
 A                                    43'First Name'
 A                                    63'Phone'
 A                                    82'Email'
 A          R TOTAL                     SPACEB(1)
 A            CUSTONO   R              2SPACEB(4)
 A                                      REFFLD(CUSTSREC/CUSTONO MyLib/CUS-
 A                                      TOMERS)
 A            CLNAME    R             14REFFLD(CUSTSREC/CLNAME MyLib/CUST-
 A                                      OMERS)
 A            CFNAME    R             36REFFLD(CUSTSREC/CFNAME MyLib/CUST-
 A                                      OMERS)
 A            CPHONE    R             54REFFLD(CUSTSREC/CPHONE MyLib/CUST-
 A                                      OMERS)
 A            CEMAIL    R             66REFFLD(CUSTSREC/CEMAIL MyLib/CUST-
 A                                      OMERS)

 A*%%RS+<record-sequences>
 A*%%RS+ <sequence name="Custlist">
 A*%%RS+  <device type="printer" width="132" height="66" />
 A*%%RS+  <record-write record-format="HEADER" />
 A*%%RS+  <record-write record-format="DETAIL" />
 A*%%RS+  <record-write record-format="TOTAL" />
 A*%%RS+ </sequence>
 A*%%RS </record-sequences>
```

Comment: in my opinion, get rid of REFFLD. Especially in context of a printed report. Fields are routinely clipped on a report to fit within the confines of the printed page.

Comment: Please correct the question from DSPF to PRTF.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have any data fields in your DETAIL record, instead they are in the TOTAL record...

Your PRTF should look more like so

```
 A          R HEADER                     
 A                                  2 55'Customer List'
 A                                  2 97DATE
 A                                  2117PAGNBR
 A                                  4  3'Customer Number'
 A                                  4 25'Last Name '
 A                                  4 43'First Name'
 A                                  4 63'Phone'
 A                                  4 82'Email'
 A          R DETAIL                    SPACEB(1)
 A            CUSTONO   R              2
 A                                      REFFLD(CUSTSREC/CUSTONO MyLib/CUS-
 A                                      TOMERS)
 A            CLNAME    R             14REFFLD(CUSTSREC/CLNAME MyLib/CUST-
 A                                      OMERS)
 A            CFNAME    R             36REFFLD(CUSTSREC/CFNAME MyLib/CUST-
 A                                      OMERS)
 A            CPHONE    R             54REFFLD(CUSTSREC/CPHONE MyLib/CUST-
 A                                      OMERS)
 A            CEMAIL    R             66REFFLD(CUSTSREC/CEMAIL MyLib/CUST-
 A                                      OMERS)
 A          R TOTAL                     SPACEB(2)
 A                                    10'Total Count:'
 A            COUNT            2 0    +2
```

Comment: You are correct. @Charles.   I also had to add the column names titles to the HEADER record to stop those from repeating. Thanks